# How to skip multiple lines of code after a config.ini file load?

Tags: python, configparser

So, I'm writing a Python script and I have a bit of code that asks the user if the user wants to load that configuration file:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser()

    if os.path.exists("path\\to\\config.ini"):
        load_save = input("Would you like to load your configuration (Y or N): ")
        if load_save == "Y":
            config.read("config.ini")

            delay = config.get("", "")
            s_key = config.get("", "")
            e_key = config.get("", "")
            button = config.get("", "")
```

But now I want the rest of the code:

```
a = float(input("input: "))
    a = a

    b = input("input: ")
    b = KeyCode(char=b)

    c = input("input: ")
    c = KeyCode(char=c)

    button = input("""input.

1) 1
2) b

Choice: """)
    if button == '1':
        button = Button.left
    elif button == '2':
        button = Button.right
    else:
        pass

    save_config = input("Would you like to save the configuration (Y or N): ")
    if save_config == "Y":
        config.read("config.ini")
        config.add_section("Configuration")
        config.set("", "", f"{}")
        config.set("", "", f"{}")
        config.set("", "", f"{}")
        if button == Button.left:
            config.set("", "", f"{}")
        elif button == Button.right:
            config.set("", "", f"{}")

        with open("config.ini", "w") as f:
            config.write(f)
    else:
        pass
```

to be skipped (it's not in a while loop). Can that be done?

Comment: Did you mean to remove the rest of the code?

Comment: Add an `else` statement after your `if` and include the code you don't want to run?

Comment: @quamrana No, I want to skip this code if the user decides to load the configuration file.

Comment: Ok, so you just need an `else:`, plus indent everything following and you're good to go.